# What about this ので

Tags: grammar, particle-の

For full context, see [here](https://www.docdroid.net/dEbqqGI/img-20170816-0001-new.pdf).

The sentence in question from line 22:

> そうですか。そのトップ社ので、ほかの色はありませんか。

ので in sense of "because" wouldn't work here I think.
Instead, I think it is the particle の + (の中)で.
Here's a literal translation which I hope reflects what I mean:

> "I see. Out of these トップ社 products, do you have other colors?"

Or is it something else?

Comment: If it were the ので meaning "because", it would have been トップ社**な**ので

Answer (score 3):

That is correct. In this case 「ので」 is the short version of 「の物で」 or 「の商品で」 as you translated.